# I don’t understand the difference between the 3 options in this context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, ielts

> The investigation into the influence of money on happiness suggests that the two are not _____________.

Options: D) related E) independent or F) relevant.
Answer is D

But why D?

Comment: 'Not independent' is a double negative, and 'not relevant' would make the sentence meaningless.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But would you be able to break that down for me? Is ‘not relevant’ not used in the English language (irrelevant) thus why it’s meaningless?  And how is ‘not independent’ a double negative?

Comment: If something isn't relevant, it has nothing to do with the subject being discussed. It makes no sense to speak about an investigation into a topic and then say that topic isn't relevant.

Comment: Thank you for explaining F), and what your take on E?

Comment: _Independent_ means _not dependent_, so _not independent_ is a double negative.

Answer (score 1):

@Cham, you can see that your question itself is being downvoted. That's unfortunate, since you're a brand new contributor, but I think I know why. I'll try to answer your question, but in doing so explain what I think the problem is. That may then let you edit your question to make it possible to answer more clearly.

So, first I'll note that the rest of us can interpret your question in (at least) two different ways. One is as if you had asked it something like this:

> Why would it be correct to say that an investigation into the influence of money on happiness suggests that those two things are not "related"; and why would it not be correct to say that they were either not "independent", or not "relevant"?

Now, I think most of the in-comment answers you're getting are taking that interpretation. And they're doing quite a good job in attempting that, because in fact the question itself, interpreted like that, is *very* vague. In fact it's actually not at all clear, just from the text you provided, that D) *is* the "correct" answer. And I suspect this is why some people are choosing to downvote instead of trying to answer. It's arguable your question just can't be answered.

However, the second way we could read your question is to notice that it is actually question 11 from this [IELTS reading practice test](https://ieltstrainingonline.com/ielts-reading-practice-test-72-with-answers/) and to interpret it as if you had written:

> In the context of this IELTS practice test, why is D) the correct answer?

And under that interpretation, there is only one way of answering your question, which is:

> The answer is D) because **that is what is said in the reading part of the test.**

This particular IELTS practice test is a reading *interpretation* test. It is asking if you understood *what* was in the text; it is *not* asking *why* the text said what it did.

Overall, I think you intended the second interpretation. And so my answer stands. The correct answer is D) because the test text says so. If the test text had said that the influence of money on happiness was "two Oreo cookies and a fat squirrel", then *that* would have been the correct answer (although I'd then advise you to go find a new source of practice tests! ). If I'm right, you could improve your question by referring to the test in question.

But if I'm wrong, and you actually intended the first meaning, then I don't think your question even fits ell.stackexchange. It's just too vague. At the moment I think most people are taking the second interpretation, and that's why you are getting downvoted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! English is not my first language. The above passage was in print so I couldn’t really type in the whole passage as it would be a waste of my study time and the answer for this question was missing. I don’t plan on contributing ( due to my poor English) I couldn’t find any english forums to help me out with my question, until I found this. Apologies if my questions seemed out of place,  I am new after all. Thanks again for the advice!